A few times I've drunk/I drank it until I've felt/I felt terribly sick... - Which one to choose?
Two friends have a casual conversation over a cup of coffee:

Jim: "Last week I was at this birthday party where I drank a full bottle of Absinthe; it was crazy! Tell me, have you ever drunk a bottle of Absinthe before?"
Matthew: "No, but I remember a few times I've drunk it/I drank it until I've felt/I felt terribly sick, maybe after three or four shots, because It's really too strong for me."

Is the Matthew's answer correct and which tense should I choose here? I would go with the present perfect because there is no any specific time references implied or suggested.

The drink called absinthe is not a proper noun in English, so should not be capitalised, just as we do not capitalise sherry, whisky, port, lager, etc. This is despite what you may see on 'mixology' websites. In 1918 Pernod Fils established a factory in Tarragona, Spain, to manufacture both absinthe and a similar beverage, without wormwood, for export to those countries prohibiting true absinthe. Whether absinthe has hallucinogenic effects remains unclear. (Britannica)

Perhaps you did drink a full bottle of absinthe and just don't remember.

Use the Past Simple because even if no time expression is mentioned, the speaker remembers when he drank the alcohol and felt ill.
The slightly modified sentence below is grammatical

Matthew: "No, but I remember the few times I drank it– maybe three or four shots– and I was / felt terribly sick because it was really too strong for me."


Thanks! Just one more question: If I said "No, but there's been a few times when I've drunk it–maybe three or four shots–until I've felt terribly sick, because It's really too strong for me.", would it be correct?

The Present Perfect is fine in that sentence because the focus is on the number of times you drank this alcohol, and you didn't say how long ago it happened. The listener's attention is drawn to the present, you're saying that today the spirit is too strong for your taste. But nothing impedes you from drinking it again at some point in the future. P.S You could also use the Simple Past, (when I drank it… I felt terribly sick…) with little to no difference in meaning.

The present perfect is overused in that revised four-shot absinthe history. You could say "until I felt terribly sick". No need for that to be stated in the present perfect. And you could also say "On several occasions" instead of "There's been a few times".  "There's been" presents an existential fact, and an existential opening doesn't comport well with the process of drinking until you felt sick, which is rooted in time. You could also use the participle to abstract the act of drinking:  On several occasions, drinking just three or four shots of absinthe made me feel terribly sick.

@TimR  I didn't  know I should have rewritten the whole sentence for the OP. Can you downvote an answer based on a comment? Live and learn...

It was your appraisal that the present perfect is "fine" in the sentence  because it "focused on the number of times you drank this alcohol and you didn't say how long ago it happened" in the comment and because, in the answer, "no time expression is mentioned" but the speaker is "remembering".  I think your rewritten sentence is fine, but the speaker's sentences lack focus or the focus wanders, I should say.

@TimR the Present Perfect in a comment not in the answer. By the way, I stand by my analysis, note I also suggested using the Past Simple,  but I agree with you the PP is overused in the sample that the OP posted in a comment.

Now answers can be downvoted if a user disagrees with their comment. Once again, I live and learn.
